# How to forward mails without having to store them on the server before?

Tags: linux, email, forwarding

as said above I want to create temporary email addresses which only forward a received message to another (external) email address. When possible without haveing to store the entire mail on the server.
Can that be realized? Thanks in advance for your comments.

I'm using qmail on Debian etch and want to store the aliases inside a database (mysql or maybe redis).
It would be enough when I get a rough prototype working. Working out specifics like file/db IO, security or performance is secondary in the first step.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Besides using static aliases it's quite easy to configure a `.qmail-default` file as a catch-all which calls a script doing lookups and forward your mails accordingly. Here's a well-known example:

http://qmail.org/top.html#databaselookup

In your lookup program, you can easily used environment variables set by qmail to identify the address catched by the catch-all; in this case the `DEFAULT` environment variable which matches the address the catch-all catched.

Regarding "without haveing to store the entire mail on the server": The mail will not go into any local Maildir, but for sure qmail will have to store it in its queue - there's no way around that. I don't know the exact reason *why* you don't want the mail to be stored on the server. If you tell us your concrete problem, maybe we'll be able to address it in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Just create some aliases in your qmail configuration. See http://lifewithqmail.org/lwq.html#aliases on how to do it.